Is Emilia actually Satella? If so, how and why?
Is Emilia actually Satella? Based on what I've seen so far it looks as if she is her, but how and why are my questions.

Pretty much the same question is asked here: How and why is Emilia connected to Satella (the Witch of Envy) and the Witch Cult?.
